Photos app: Why aren’t all days shown in “Collections: Days”?
After updating to Sequoia, Photos app now has a “Collections: Days” choice in the sidebar. But not all days are shown, only some days at random. Why is that? Where are all the other days?
For example, in “Days” right now I see “Sep 17”, “Sep 14, 2024”, “Sep 3”, “Sep 2”, and into August. But in “Libary: All Photos”, I see photos from October 14, 13, 12, 7, 4, September 30, 28, 19, 17, 14, 13, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, and into August.

Firstly, this is not a defect on your computer - I see the same thing.
It appears that it only creates an entry when a certain threshold of photos is reached. For example, if you take a single photo it won't create an entry for the day.
It is likely designed to create entries for days that have multiple sets of photos that can be collected together.
